# How do I dynamically set validations fields in vuelidate

Tags: validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm using VueJS2 with [vuelidate](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate) library. I can validate the fields based on the validation objects. The validation will execute during computed time. But My validations objects is fixed, instead of dynamic. I have some fields will hide based on the selection.

```
import { validationMixin } from 'vuelidate'
import { required, maxLength, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
mixins: [validationMixin],
validations: {
  company_name: { required },
  company_position_title: { required }
},
methods: {
  submit(){
    this.$v.touch();
    if(this.$v.$invalid == false){ 
      // All validation fields success
    }
  }
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<v-select
  label="Who are you?"
  v-model="select" // can be 'company' or 'others'
  :items="items"
  :error-messages="selectErrors"
  @change="$v.select.$touch();resetInfoFields();"
  @blur="$v.select.$touch()"
  required
></v-select>

<v-text-field
  label="Company Name"
  v-model="company_name"
  :error-messages="companyNameErrors"
  :counter="150"
  @input="$v.companyName.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.companyName.$touch()"
  v-show="select == 'Company'"
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
  label="Company Position Title"
  v-model="company_position_title"
  :error-messages="companyPositionErrors"
  :counter="150"
  @input="$v.companyPosition.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.companyPosition.$touch()"
  v-show="select == 'Company'"
></v-text-field>

<v-btn @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
```

**Problem**

When I select 'other' option and click submit, the `this.$v.$invalid` is still true. It should be false as there is no validation fields required. 
When I select 'company', that two fields must required and validated.

Answer (score 15):

you need a dynamic validation schema

```
validations () {
  if (!this.select === 'company') {
    return {
      company_name: { required },
      company_position_title: { required }
    }
  }
}
```

More info: [Dynamic validation schema](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-dynamic-validation-schema)

Comment: says its $dirty of undefined

Comment: You cannot use an if statement inside an object declaration.

Answer (score 7):

Another way is using requiredIf

```
itemtocheck: {
  requiredIf: requiredIf(function () {
    return this.myitem !== 'somevalue'
  }),
  minLength: minLength(2) },
```

Comment: minLength will still be applied, so it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it's done with Vue3 + composition API according to [the docu](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/examples.html#composition-api).

```
const state = reactive({
  shippingAddress: '',
  billingSameAsShipping: false,
  billingAddress: ''
})
const rules = computed(() => {
  const localRules = {
    shippingAddress: { required }
  }
  if (!state.billingSameAsShipping) {
    // if billing is not the same as shipping, require it
    localRules.billingAddress = {
      required
    }
  }
  return localRules
})
const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state)
```